How to apply a custom conditional format to a pivot table using Excel Scripts
It is straightforward to manually apply custom conditional formatting to parts of a pivot table. However, when trying to do it with Office Scripts, see snippet below, the following error is thrown:

Range addConditionalFormat: The requested resource doesn’t exist.

The code works perfectly if the cell does not belong to a pivot table. Can anyone reproduce this error? Is this a limitation of Office Scripts?
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
const sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
const d = sheet.getRange("b6");
const pos = d.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.custom).getCustom();
pos.getFormat().getFill().setColor("lightgreen");
pos.getFormat().getFont().setBold(true);
pos.getRule().setFormula(`=${d.getCell(0, 0).getAddress()}>300`); }


I don't think ExcelScript supports conditional formatting of pivot tables - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/pivottables
